The Operation couldn't be completed. No APNS token specified before fetching FCM Token
I am trying to integrate push notifications in iOS through Firebase in React Native. But I am getting the following warning the physical device and am unable to get the notifications even after creating the project in firebase, creating key and identifiers in apple developer account and uploading .p8 file in firebase along with team ID.
Tried various things from stackoverflow but nothing helped.

follow the steps given in this https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/notifications
